# Curl FTPS upload with username:password syntax

Tags: curl, uploading, ftps

So the curl man pages say to do this for an upload:

```
curl --upload-file "{file1,file2}" http://www.example.com
```

or

```
curl -T "img[1-1000].png" ftp://ftp.example.com/upload/
```

I know how to establish a connection...here's my command which works.

```
curl -k --user myusername:mypassword ftps://ftp.yourftp.com
```

But the man pages don't list how to establish a connection and upload a file. Only how to upload a file. So what's the correct syntax here for connecting and uploading? How do I combine the last command of establishing a connection with the curl upload commands?

Answer (score 1):

Just an update, here's what I use for MacOS, for anyone else that's wondering. You can include variables too. (This is Zsh)

```
curl -g -k -T ~/Documents/myfile.txt ftps://myusername:mypassword@ftp.website.com/mydirectorypath/

curl -g -k -T ~/Documents/$(echo "$myfile")_.txt ftps://myusername:mypassword@ftp.website.com/mydirectorypath/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -k -T /localfilepath/temptestfile.txt ftps://yourusername:yourpassword@ftp.yourftp.com/somedirectory/
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is looking the answer for the ftp protocol (I googled it and found this question):

`curl -T local_file.txt -u "login:password" ftp://my-ftp-server.com/remote/ftp/path/`

It is also possible to use `-n` option instead of `-u` with curl to use `~/.netrc` file for storing password information (might be safer in scripts).